# Lost right-click functionality on a hyperlink that submits a POST form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink that submits a hidden form via POST to another site. 
However, if you right click this particular hyperlink and try to open it in a new tab, it only opens a blank new tab instead of going to the site.

It does not function like how a user would expect a hyperlink to function.

Is there a way to regain this lost functionality when having hyperlinks submit POST forms? If not, is there a better way to do have a hyperlink send a POST request without losing the functionality to right click it into a new tab?

Example:

```
<form id="my_form" method="POST" action="http://foo.bar">
    <input type="hidden" name"foo" value="bar">
</form>

<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('my_form').submit();">hyperlink</a>
```

Comment: You can't run Javascript of one page in a tab that opens another page.

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to run JavaScript on another page, I'm trying to submit the form to another page. Is there now way to override the default behavior for when the user right clicks something to open it in a new tab?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="my_form" method="POST" action="http://foo.bar">
    <input type="hidden" name"foo" value="bar">
</form>

<a href="enter/url/to/site/here" onclick="event.preventDefault();javascript:document.getElementById('my_form').submit();">hyperlink</a>
```

If you must keep it all inline you can do the above. The onclick event will take over the action on the link but you will still be able to right click and access the href attribute. I would opt for moving this out of line though.

Comment: This does not appear to submit the form, even when profiling with dev tools, it just opens the current site in a new tab. I've tried various values for the href too.

Comment: Hi Bill it worked for me doing a post to one of my forms on my sever. It passed the inputs over just fine and still preserved the ability to do a right click on the href. Can you post me your actual code vs foo bar type of examples. Maybe I will catch something there.